# Android, Is it possible to integrate Twitter into Android application without using callback?

Tags: android, twitter, integration

In my application I need to integrate twitter into my application. I tried to integrate it with callback url and everything was fine. I could sent my message successfully and see that message on my page.

However, adding callback url into twitter made problem for iPhone app. Now, I need to find a way to send my message without using callback url.

I searched the Internet and unfortunately all tutorials were based on callback method. Is it possible to send message without using callback method? If you know any documentation please share it with me.

Thanks

Comment: When you say callback - you mean OAuth authorization?

Comment: Thanks dear Yahor10. The method that has been used by Twitter is OAuth which is using to authenticate users. In page of application (https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) there is a callback filed which return navigation after successfully authentication. I want to know is there anyway to get successful login without filling this field?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid navigation url you can use Htmlunit and authorize your form programmatically.
Here the same issue with dropbox: http://wastedcodetime.blogspot.com/?view=sidebar